# Execute javascript based on # in target URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, checkout, fragment-identifier

when someone clicks an element that points to #**checkoutID** I'd like to execute a script.

this is the element:

```
<a class="lp-element lp-pom-button" id="lp-pom-button-293" href="**#checkoutID**" target="_self" data-params="true"><span class="label">Checkout</span></a>
```

this is the script:

```
stripe.redirectToCheckout({
  lineItems: [{
    price: '{{checkoutID}}', 
    quantity: 1,
  }],
  mode: 'payment',
  successUrl: 'https://example.com/success',
  cancelUrl: 'https://example.com/cancel',
}).then(function (result) {
});
```

I'm struggling with retrieving the string after # to see if it contains "checkout" and then execute the script by using the **checkoutID** as a value for price, which in this example, the price value is just an ID of the item. Would anyone be kind enough to provide some pointers here. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the current url you can use

```
window.location.href;
```

And, if you want to call a function on some event, use:

```
document.querySelector(‘#bttonOrElementID’).addEventListener(‘click’, function(){
//your function goes here
});
```

Comment: `window.location.hash` would be more concise, as explained in the duplicate's answers.